# Nested loops with linear array

Tags: c++, array, iteration

i have found this article on how to loop through multi-dimensional arrays quickly. 
http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/06/c_c_tip_how_loop_through_multi_dimensional_arrays_quickly

I am using Method 6: Nested loops with linear array and single incrementing index.
It says Method 8: Single loop with linear array and incrementing index is faster. 
but i require nested loops indexes as well. when i try to calculate the nested loops indexes via if clauses. my code slows down(at least worst than nested loop approach) can you recommend anything for calculating individual indexes.

```
 int x1=0,x2=0; 
  for (int i1 = 1; i1 <= 10000; i1++){
             for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){


                x1++;
                if(x1>100){
                    x1=0;
                    x2++;
                 }
                 a[i] = 0;
                 if (x1 > 10)
                 {
                     a[i] += a[i - 10*1];
                 }
                 if (x2 < 95)
                 {
                     a[i] += a[i + 5*100];
                 }
             }
         }
```

for  multidimensional array structure a[x1][x2]. I want to calculate a[x1][x2]=a[x1-10][x2]+a[x1][x2+5] which a[x1][x2] is converted to a[x1+x2*100]

program code
http://ideone.com/oKVdQI

Is there a way I can improve this code in terms of speed?

Comment: The ;lack of context and generic variable names makes this look like hypothetical code.  If this isn't the case, then post the real code and its purpose.

Comment: The best way to improve this code is to remove the `if` statements from the loop.  Branches inside loops kill performance. So convert the inner loop into three different loops (with no if statement). **BUT** a good compiler/hardware will automatically do that for you with branch prediction code http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/14065

Comment: @jamal full function code is posted

Comment: Your first chunk of code mentions `i1` but doesn't use it. Also, it appears to do nothing at all to the array `a`. So you basically have a 100 million step loop that does nothing?

Comment: yes abstraction is a little bit hard to understand. but i wanted to improve the second code.

Comment: @AyleanClaraGrandieur: Could you please post the whole code with all the variable definitions. Right now the code is very hard to review since it is entirely unclear what the types of all the involved variables are. Ideally the code you post can be copied and pasted and compiled without changes.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. You're running the code 10K times to see how long it takes to run. What is the main code actually trying to achieve? There may be an easier way to do the same thing.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to be asking for `a [ i + 500 ]` when setting `a [ i ]`? You haven't assigned anything to that memory (in what you've posted, anyway), so the value is undefined.

Comment: you can check program code that a is populated with random numbers